# Initializer list makes variable uninitialized?

Tags: c++, initialization, valgrind, ctor-initializer

I have a class with the only constructor like this:

```
IntroScreen::IntroScreen(Game *game) :
    View(game), counter(0.0f), message(-1), continueAlpha(255),
    continueVisible(false), screenAlpha(255), fadeIn(false), fadeOut(false)
{
}
```

And somewhere in a method I have this if-statement

```
if (counter > 10.0f)
```

And Valgrind says for that line:

> Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

But I initialized it in my initializer list! And I think I believe Valgrind. Because, sometimes everything goes correct and sometimes nothing happens.... So, maybe `counter` gets a wrong value and so it takes long until the counter reaches 10.

I already check my code where I use counter for some errors. But I think you can't "un-initialize a value" with a C++ statement...

These are ALL the lines (except in the initializer list) where I use `counter`:

```
counter += speed;
counter = 20.0f;
counter += game->getSpeedFactor();
if (counter >= 15.f)
counter = 15.f;
if (counter > 10.0f)
```

Valgrind gives the same output for `screenAlpha`.

Both variables are `private` and I have no `friend` classes....

So, what is going on? What the problem could be?

**Edit:**

I printed the value out:
In the constructor, it was correnct: `0`
In my method, it was rubbish. It prited random values like:

- `-97298.8...`
- `-106542.2...`

The print statement is the first line of the method where all assignments to `counter` are in.

### **Second Edit:**

Can this be the problem!!??

In my `Game` class, I initialize that `IntroScreen` like this:

```
Game::Game() : /* Some other stuff .... */  , view(new IntroScreen(this))`
{}
```

`view` is here a pointer to an abstract super-type of `IntroScreen` called `View`.

Comment: Could `15.f` be the problem?

Comment: `valgrind` can do mistakes too. That's why suppression-lists exist.

Comment: No, I changed all `xx.f` to `xx.0f`  It changed nothing. But thanks...

Comment: Based on your lines, it is still possible that getSpeedFactor() returns an uninitialized value, which is only flagged when using it (in the if (...)) statement.

Comment: Things I'd like to be assured of:  The list of statements containing `counter` was done by an automatic process, and hence is exhaustive. (It bothers me that I don't see a definition.) You don't have any other constructors of any sort (like an explicit copy constructor), or any sort of assignment operator, for `IntroScreen`.  You have checked, and you do initialize `IntroScreen` before attempting to use it (i.e., no `IntroScreen * foo; foo -> SomeFunction(); foo = new Introscreen;`).

Comment: What's the close vote for? Go close something else silly fella.

Comment: Together with the value of `counter`, also print `this`, so you see which object you're printing the counter of.

Comment: @Vulcan: Martijn [asked to "please close the question"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266679/c-initializer-list-makes-variable-uninitialized/3267301#3267301).

Comment: @Martijn: I think you can close your own question all by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it:

`getSpeedFactor()` returns only the first time I call it a complete wrong number because of time-functions like `gettimeofday()`. The start value (to time how long it took to update the game) is set initialized to zero and the stop value is micros of the day: which gives a time of the whole day instead of the update time.  Once the game loop ran once, the wrong value is corrected (because of the start value gets assigned). But the first time the game-logic was executed, I used  `getSpeedFactor()` to assign `counter`, so that way `counter` get a value of -10000...

Thanks all.

Answer (score 6):

Did you accidentally shadow `counter` with a local variable that's uninitialized?

Otherwise, it's possible that valgrind is mid-diagnosing this in an object that was already deleted (using sentry values perhaps).

Or valgrind could just be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Not enough code to reproduce problem.

Generic SO / developer forum advice:

**Do provide a minimal code snippet reproducing the problem.**

Quite often (about 85% of all cases in my experience) the process of reducing the code snippet already uncovers the bug for you.

---

**Edit:** Your addition still doesn't give a compilable example of your problem, but enough information at least to identify then problem - or, at least, one of them:

```
Game::Game() : /* Some other stuff .... */  , view(new IntroScreen(this))`
{}
```

I am not sure whether a `new()` call is even legal in an initializer list. But I *am* sure that you do not have a fully initialized `this` at this point, so chances are your `IntroScreen` constructor does bogus things.

Comment: This is very true and if it was a comment, I'd love to up-vote it. But it is no real answer and as such needs a down-vote.

Comment: @ sbi: Well? It's the best answer I could give at the time. And I think it's helpful advice for the OP, so I don't believe a downvote is appropriate. But opinions differ.

Comment: (I didn't see your first answering comment, because of the space between the `@` and my nick.) I removed my down-vote.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, you may need to define private default and copy constructors that have proper initializers.  Haven't used valgrind, but it's a common thing to forget to do.

Comment: If my memory serves me well, defining *any* constructor disables automatic generation of default constructor, so that one shouldn't matter. And automatic copy constructor would copy all the fields anyway…

Answer (score 0):

Just add a debugging printf statement or equivalent, if you have doubts. But I would not believe Valgrind this time.

BTW: delete does not "un-initliase" a value. It deletes object, but the pointer still points to that memory location — it does have a value.